# Too many re-renders caused by a custom React Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am loading data in from a Neo4J database using [use-neo4j](https://github.com/adam-cowley/use-neo4j) and have created a custom hook. It makes a query to the database and then converts the data to a format I can use for plotting the data.

It is a lot of code but basically `neo4jToJSON` converts the data from Neo4J, then I set it to the state, lastly I return the state to be used in other components.

**Note:**

Before this I was just returning `neo4jToJSON`  and had no issues. But the moment I incorporate state into the function and return the state it throws this error.

**Edit:**

I have tried the suggested answer in the updated code below but now the data just returns undefined.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useReadCypher } from "use-neo4j";

const useFetchData = () => {
  const [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState();
  // Query to Neo4j database to get all the relevant data for all the users
  const getAllUserData = // a query string that is quite long so I didn't include it 
  // Pass query to use-neo4j to get the data
  const { result } = useReadCypher(getAllUserData);

  const filters = [
    "name",
    "longitude",
    "latitude",
    "agreeableness",
    "openness",
    "neuroticism",
    "extraversion",
    "conscientiousness",
    "angry",
    "fear",
    "joy",
    "sadness",
    "love",
    "country",
    "question1",
    "question2",
    "question3",
    "question4",
    "question5",
    "question6",
    "question7",
    "question8",
    "question9",
    "question10",
    "question11",
    "question12",
    "question13",
    "question14",
    "question15",
    "question16",
    "question17",
    "question18",
    "question19",
    "question20",
    "question21",
    "question22",
    "question23",
    "question24",
    "question25",
    "question26",
    "question27",
    "question28",
    "question29",
    "question30",
    "question31",
    "question32",
    "question33",
    "question34",
    "question35",
    "question36",
    "question37",
    "question38",
    "question39",
    "question40",
    "question41",
  ];
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (result) {
      const { records } = result;

      const neo4jToJSON =
        records &&
        records.map(({ _fields }) => {
          // User name
          const screenName = _fields[0];
          // Country of the user
          const country = _fields[2][0];
          // Create the object with these values as the keys:
          //
          // "name",
          // "longitude",
          // "latitude",
          // "agreeableness",
          // "openness",
          // "neuroticism",
          // "extraversion",
          // "conscientiousness",
          // "angry",
          // "fear",
          // "joy",
          // "sadness",
          // "love",
          // "country"
          const userPersonality = filters.reduce((acc, curr, idx) => {
            if (idx === 0) {
              // set the property name to the screenName
              acc[curr] = screenName;
            } else if (idx >= 1 && idx <= 12) {
              // if the index is in the range of 1 to 12
              // it belongs to _fields[1]
              // set the properties of _fields[1] to their respective values
              // values come in the form of strings so apply parseFloat on them
              acc[curr] = parseFloat(_fields[1][idx - 1]);
            } else if (idx === 13) {
              // set the property country
              acc[curr] = country;
            }
            return acc;
          }, {});
          const finalResults = filters.reduce((acc, curr, idx) => {
            const questions = _fields[3];
            if (idx > 13) {
              // Access the first element of the array of arrays which contains
              // the questions by idx - 14
              // The current value starts from idx 14 of filters which is
              // question1
              // So if idx is equal to 14:
              // idx - 14 will give the question for the first question which is
              // at index 0
              //
              // Ternary operator here checks if the array value is not empty if
              // it is not empty then set the value of the current question to be
              // the array of questions
              // Else set the value to be an empty array which is falsy
              questions[idx - 14]
                ? (acc[curr] = questions[idx - 14])
                : (acc[curr] = []);
            }
            return acc;
          }, userPersonality);
          return finalResults;
        });
      setJsonData(neo4jToJSON);
    }
  }, []);
  return { jsonData };
};

export default useFetchData
```

Comment: Try to use useEffect instead of simple ```if( result ) {}```

Comment: `setJsonData` is called from within the render cycle (even if it's a hook, since these are called inside render). Move that logic into a `useEffect` and it should help.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I tried in the as per the updated question but the component that uses this data just shows that the data is `undefined`.

Comment: Add ```result``` to array passed as second argument of useEffect. ```useEffect(()=>{},[result])```

Comment: In this case, `useMemo` might be more appropriate though

Comment: @EmileBergeron could you add an answer which uses `useMemo()`?

Comment: I've added [complementary solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66678791/1218980)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a state setter synchronously from your render function. Never do this. That's what triggers the re-render. And then triggers it again, and again, and again.

```
const useFetchData = () => {
  const [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState();
  const { result } = useReadCypher(getAllUserData);

  if (result) {
    setJsonData(something);
  }
```

If you need to set some state when `result` changes you can `useEffect`

```
const useFetchData = () => {
  const [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState();
  const { result } = useReadCypher(getAllUserData);
  useEffect(() => { if (result) setJsonData(something) }, [result]);
```

Answer (score 1):

While `useEffect` is one of the way to avoid calling state setter functions inside of the render cycle, in your case, `useState` isn't needed at all!

### Compute on every render

It's an anti-pattern to use state for something that can be synchronously computed within render.

```js
const FILTERS = [
  "name",
  "longitude",
  "latitude",
  // ...etc.
];

const computeData = ({ records } = {}) => {
  return (
    records &&
    records.map(({ _fields }) => {
      const screenName = _fields[0];
      const country = _fields[2][0];
      const userPersonality = filters.reduce((acc, curr, idx) => {
        if (idx === 0) {
          acc[curr] = screenName;
        } else if (idx >= 1 && idx <= 12) {
          acc[curr] = parseFloat(_fields[1][idx - 1]);
        } else if (idx === 13) {
          acc[curr] = country;
        }
        return acc;
      }, {});
      const questions = _fields[3];
      const finalResults = filters.reduce((acc, curr, idx) => {
        if (idx > 13) {
          questions[idx - 14]
            ? (acc[curr] = questions[idx - 14])
            : (acc[curr] = []);
        }
        return acc;
      }, userPersonality);
      return finalResults;
    })
  );
};

export default function useFetchData() {
  // Query to Neo4j database to get all the relevant data for all the users
  const getAllUserData = "?whatever"; // a query string
  // Pass query to use-neo4j to get the data
  const { result } = useReadCypher(getAllUserData);

  // no need for state here, just compute on every render.
  return { jsonData: computeData(result) };
}
```

### Optimize heavy computations with [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)

If you figure that some computation only happens once when the data is received and mostly never changes, and/or it's an heavy computation that could lead to a bottleneck, consider using `useMemo` to memoize the computation result and only re-compute if the input changes.

```js
import { useMemo } from "react";

//...computeData, filters, etc. here...

export default function useFetchData() {
  // Query to Neo4j database to get all the relevant data for all the users
  const getAllUserData = "?whatever"; // a query string
  // Pass query to use-neo4j to get the data
  const { result } = useReadCypher(getAllUserData);

  // no need for state here, just memoize the result.
  const jsonData = useMemo(() => computeData(result), [result]);

  return { jsonData };
}
```

---

Also notice that in each example, I've moved some stuff around, so that the hook logic is easier to grasp and to isolate the computation logic.

Answer (score 0):

Move your logic into `useEffect` function

```
useEffect(() => {
    effect
    return () => {
        cleanup
    }
}, [input])
```

Like this

```
        useEffect(() => {
 // Query to Neo4j database to get all the relevant data for all the users
  const getAllUserData = // a query string that is quite long so I didn't include it 
  // Pass query to use-neo4j to get the data
  const { result } = useReadCypher(getAllUserData);
    if (result) {
                // Convert the data from Neo4j which comes in the form of an Object to
                // another Object that has keys which are elements in the array filters and
                // values which are the _fields from the Object from Neo4j
            
                const { records } = result;
            
                const neo4jToJSON =
                  records &&
                  records.map(({ _fields }) => {
                    // User name
                    const screenName = _fields[0];
                    // Country of the user
                    const country = _fields[2][0];
                    const userPersonality = filters.reduce((acc, curr, idx) => {
                      if (idx === 0) {
                        // set the property name to the screenName
                        acc[curr] = screenName;
                      } else if (idx >= 1 && idx <= 12) {
                        // if the index is in the range of 1 to 12
                        // it belongs to _fields[1]
                        // set the properties of _fields[1] to their respective values
                        // values come in the form of strings so apply parseFloat on them
                        acc[curr] = parseFloat(_fields[1][idx - 1]);
                      } else if (idx === 13) {
                        // set the property country
                        acc[curr] = country;
                      }
                      return acc;
                    }, {});
                    const finalResults = filters.reduce((acc, curr, idx) => {
                      const questions = _fields[3];
                      if (idx > 13) {
                        // Access the first element of the array of arrays which contains
                        // the questions by idx - 14
                        // The current value starts from idx 14 of filters which is
                        // question1
                        // So if idx is equal to 14:
                        // idx - 14 will give the question for the first question which is
                        // at index 0
                        //
                        // Ternary operator here checks if the array value is not empty if
                        // it is not empty then set the value of the current question to be
                        // the array of questions
                        // Else set the value to be an empty array which is falsy
                        questions[idx - 14]
                          ? (acc[curr] = questions[idx - 14])
                          : (acc[curr] = []);
                      }
                      return acc;
                    }, userPersonality);
                    return finalResults;
                  });
                setJsonData(neo4jToJSON);
              }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this and in the component I am using it just returns `undefined`.

Comment: if `useReadCypher ` is async function (if so use async - await), then call this function also inside useEffect. @yudhiesh I have updated the answer check once.